# How can I customise SharPoint Online List View Mode in Excel OData Power Query code?

Tags: excel, sharepoint, powerquery

The [2.0 implementation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-query/connectors/sharepointonlinelist#connect-to-sharepoint-online-list-v20-beta) offers two view modes.
**How can I customise the query to change the view mode manually?**
[image]

I'm on business version of Excel, so I have no access to the SharePoint connector shown above.
I use OData connector, of which this is the resulting query:

```
let
    Source = OData.Feed("https://company.sharepoint.com/sites/yoursite/_vti_bin/ListData.svc", null, [Implementation="2.0"]),
    List1 = Source{[Name="List1",Signature="table"]}[Data]
in
    List1
```

Side question: **would this reduce the amount of data loaded or is it the same as using Power Query to remove the extra columns?**
I know Power Query supports query folding and that it should work with SharePoint, but it seems to perform a lot better in PowerApps for example, where I am able to select the View Mode.

Comment: you can create view for the sharepoint list in the web version of the list.

Comment: Sorry @Rosetta, that's not what I'm after exactly. I'm trying to find out how to select specific list view in the query.

Comment: i'm afraid i didn't know that, looking at the documentation it seems like its not possible. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/odata-feed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've finally found the answer on [biinsight.com](https://biinsight.com/optimising-odata-refresh-performance-in-power-query-for-power-bi-and-excel/), full credit to the author.

We can utilise OData query to make SharePoint filter the list before serving by specifying the list and (optionally) any filtering query like this:
`.../_vti_bin/ListData.svc/YourList?$select=ID,Name,Age&$filter=Age gt 26`

Which returns only columns `ID`,`Name` & `Age` and records where `Age` is greater than 26.